# How can I add unique id to a custom cell?

Tags: testing, gwt, cell

In a gwt project I have a CellTree with custom cells. For easier testing I would like to add IDs for each of the cells.
I know I can make it like this :

```
@Override
public void render(Context context,TreeElement value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {             
            if (value == null) {return;}
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div id=\""+value.getID()+"\">" + 
                                       value.getName()) + "</div>"; 
}
```

But I would like to use something similar to EnsureDebugID() so I don't have to burn the IDs in the code. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something between the two of the aforementioned approaches. You should definitely add a prefix to be sure you can easily identify the cells during testing, and you should also take the [`createUniqueId()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html#createUniqueId%28%29) approach rather than generating your own UUIDs which can be more troublesome.

```
@Override
public void render(Context context, TreeElement value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {             
    if (value == null) {return;}
    String id = Document.get().createUniqueId();
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div id=\"cell_"+id+"\">" + 
                           value.getName()) + "</div>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Document.get().createUniqueId();
```

Here the description:

```
/**
   * Creates an identifier guaranteed to be unique within this document.
   * 
   * This is useful for allocating element id's.
   * 
   * @return a unique identifier
   */
  public final native String createUniqueId() /*-{
    // In order to force uid's to be document-unique across multiple modules,
    // we hang a counter from the document.
    if (!this.gwt_uid) {
      this.gwt_uid = 1;
    }

    return "gwt-uid-" + this.gwt_uid++;
  }-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when I do this sort of thing I add a prefix to it.  so ID="sec_22" where sec_ is the prefix.  Then I know that section has something unique.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to set an id to a TextCell and I did like this

```
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.TextCell;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.client.SafeHtmlTemplates;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlBuilder;

public class EnsuredDbgIdTextCell extends TextCell {

    private static EnsuredDbgIdTextCellTemplate template = null;

    public EnsuredDbgIdTextCell() {
        super();
        if (template == null) {
            template = GWT.create(EnsuredDbgIdTextCellTemplate.class);
        }
    }

    public interface EnsuredDbgIdTextCellTemplate extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
        @Template("<div id=\"{0}\" style=\"outline:none;\" tabindex=\"0\">{0}</div>")
        SafeHtml withValueAsDebugId(String value);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, SafeHtml value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (value != null) {
            sb.append(template.withValueAsDebugId(value.asString()));
        }
    }

}
```

I set the id equals to the text value.