# GWT: How do I assign an ID to editable table cells in a CellTable?

Tags: gwt, celltable, gwt-celltable

I'm using GWT 2.4.  I'm constructing a CellTable with some editable table cells.  My question is, when the cells are rendered, how do I force them to be rendered with a "name" and/or "id" attribute defined within the input tag?  Right now, the code I have for rendering the cell is ...

```
class EditableTableCell extends TextInputCell {
    private final List<Node> colData;

    public EditableTableCell(final List<Node> colData) { 
        super();
        this.colData = colData;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        final Integer index = context.getIndex();
        final Node childNode = colData.get(index); 

        if (childNode.getAttributes() != null && 
            childNode.getAttributes().get("edit") != null &&
            childNode.getAttributes().get("edit").getValue() != null &&
            childNode.getAttributes().get("edit").getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) { 
            super.render(context,value,sb);
        } else { 
            sb.appendEscaped(value);
        }   // if
    }
}
```

If the cell is editable, the resulting html looks like ...

```
<td class="GCSPOWVPD GCSPOWVBE GCSPOWVCE GCSPOWVME">
    <div style="outline:none;" tabindex="0">
        <input type="text" value="\n\t\t\tABC\n\t\t" tabindex="-1"></input>
    </div>
</td>
```

Although "type", "value", and "tabindex" get defined, no "name" or "id".  Trying to figure out how to do this.  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you're doing `super.render(...)`, I would instead render that HTML myself, and stick in a name and id value for the `input` element manually. I answered a similar question on this concept [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123354/how-can-i-add-unique-id-to-a-custom-cell/8123960#8123960). Idea is slightly different, but implementation would be the same.